# How to change the size of the title and the numbers in a histogram in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to increase the size of the title of each histogram and also increase the size of the number in the axis.

```
axs = regiao_nota_MT['NU_NOTA_MT'].hist(by = regiao_nota_MT['Regiao'], figsize=(15, 10),  facecolor='green',  alpha=0.5)

for ax in axs.flatten():
    ax.set_xlabel("NU_NOTA_MT", size = '13')
    ax.set_ylabel("Number of students", size = '13')
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ92e.png]

Comment: `for ax in axs.flatten(): ax.title.set_size(20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can globally set the size of your `axes.titles` and `ytick`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
params = {'ytick.labelsize': 12,
          'axes.titlesize': 12}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
```

More on [Customizing Matplotlib with style sheets and rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#)